# What is the common name of the soap that is put on the lavatory seat? (picture is attached)

Tags: word-request

What  is the common name of the soap that is put on the lavatory seat? 
For example if I'm in English speakers country and I'm going to the supermarket and ask the salesperson for this item, what should I call it?

[image]

Comment: Toilet seat sanitizer spray.

Comment: Do you know a word for it in any other language? I think you can just explain what you need, like "freshener that hangs on lavatory seat" or something like this.

Comment: @Khan, I don't think it is spray, take a look at the picture.

Comment: @Alissa, yes, I know, but I couldn't be translated to English. I've tried.

Comment: What you have pictured is not put **on** a toilet seat, it is **hung inside** the toilet bowl and is called a **toilet bowl flush cleaner** since it cleans what the toilet is flushed.  These can be hung inside the toilet bowl or placed in the tank (cistern) behind the toilet bowl. Something put **on** a toilet seat would be a **disinfectant** to protect your bum.

Comment: @Peter Both the [cleaners placed in the tank](https://www.clorox.com/products/clorox-automatic-toilet-bowl-cleaner-bleach-and-blue/) and the [ones clipped to the side of the toilet bowl](http://www.lysol.com/products/toilet-bowl-cleaners/lysol-no-mess-automatic-toilet-bowl-cleaner/) are called "automatic toilet bowl cleaners" in the US by the companies that make them. I've never talked about them much but I would probably have used "toilet cake" before I saw that some people actually bake cakes that look like toilets. (It's gross, don't Google it.)

Comment: @ColleenV +1 another good term to use, and Ewwww! thanks for the warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK this would most likely be known as a **[rim block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet_rim_block)**.